# sql varchar setting string null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i am using a column like `strString varchar (1500)`

and are wanting to set a part of the strString to 0x00, i am doing the following but it is not fully setting a part to 0x00...

```
DECLARE @set_part_null varchar(13)
SET @set_part_null = CAST(0 as varbinary(4)) + CAST(0 as varbinary(4)) + CAST(0 as varbinary(4))+ CAST(0 as varbinary(1))

UPDATE location_works SET strString  = SUBSTRING(strString,1,@pos) + @set_part_null + SUBSTRING(strString,@pos+13+1,1500) WHERE nfieldid = @fieldno
```

as you can see, i am trying to set 13 bytes to 0x00 in strString, but it dosen't always do that, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
Replicate( Char( 0 ), 13 )
```